# How To Apply Multiple Actions To A SUBMIT Button With Javascript, jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

I currently have a form with 3 submit buttons which pass 'FULLNAME' and 'EMAIL' and 'DB' variables via the URL depending on which submit button is clicked - these values then populate fields on the next page.

```
<form action="https://othersite.com/index.html?DB=BOTH&values[FULLNAME]&values[EMAIL]" method="get" name="form" >
<input type="hidden" name="DB" value="BOTH" />
<input type="text" id="fullname" name="values[FULLNAME]"  >
<input type="email" id="email" name="values[EMAIL]" >

<button type="submit" name="OS_TYPE" value="OSX &amp; WINDOWS">OSX &amp; WINDOWS</button>
<button type="submit" name="DB" value="OSX" formaction="https://othersite.com/index.html?DB=OSX&values[FULLNAME]&values[EMAIL]">OSX ONLY</button>
<button type="submit" name="DB" value="WINDOWS" formaction="https://othersite.com/index.html?DB=WINDOWS&values[FULLNAME]&values[EMAIL">WINDOWS ONLY</button>
</form>
```

The form above works correctly, prepopulating the FULLNAME and EMAIL fields on the 'BOTH DB', 'OSX DB' or 'WINDOWS DB' form on the 'othersite.com' page depending upon which submit button is clicked (BOTH being the default).

However, I also need to send an email with the values of FULLNAME, EMAIL and if possible DB type, preferably using formmail.php where I would specify:

1. The URL of the formmail script on my server, e.g.
   myexample.com/formmail.php
2. The send method, which is POST
3. A hidden input field containing the recipient email address for formmail
4. A hidden input field containing the subject of the email

The user would continue to be redirected to the othersite.com page depending on which submit button they click.

Any help using jQuery, javascript or PHP would be greatly appreciated. I'm a front-end developer and this is beyond my skillset!

Thanks

Comment: Post what you tried to solve your problem, would be great to get suggestion/result

Comment: I'm struggling to add more than 1 action to a SUBMIT button, as I say, back-end isn't my speciality, if the variables can be sent to formmail AND the link on the relevant SUBMIT button followed that would be great but I really don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly send an email through JavaScript. However, you can launch the email client with prefilled email address using window.open:

```
window.open('mailto:test@example.com');
```

Now, if that is what you want, in your current form remove the type="submit" attribute from button elements and call a JavaScript function when the button is clicked which will open the email client and submit your existing form:

```
<button name="OS_TYPE" value="OSX &amp; WINDOWS" onclick="submitMyForm()">OSX &amp; WINDOWS</button>
```

and create a JavaScript function that will open the email client and submit your form:

```
function submitMyForm() {
    window.open('mailto:test@example.com');
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); //attach an id to your form
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping the values could be sent 'in the background' via formmail.php script when the user clicks whichever SUBMIT button.

Comment: Is it possible using PHP, if the page containing the form was a PHP page?